# npm - gulp-sass no longer has a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, node-modules, node-sass

Keep getting this error when trying to build templates

```
[09:21:08] Requiring external module babel-register
[09:21:19] Using gulpfile ~/GIT/Newsletters/gulpfile.babel.js
[09:21:19] Starting 'build'...
[09:21:19] Starting 'clean'...
[09:21:19] Finished 'clean' after 5.98 ms
[09:21:19] Starting 'pages'...
[09:21:20] Finished 'pages' after 1.96 s
[09:21:20] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
gulp-sass no longer has a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the "sass" and "node-sass" packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:
 const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

When I then add `const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));` in my **gulpfile.js**

It gives this error

```
[09:41:01] Requiring external module babel-register
{ TypeError: /Users/lde4k1v/GIT/Newsletters/gulpfile.babel.js: Duplicate declaration "sass"
  76 | 
  77 | // Compile Sass into CSS
> 78 | function sass() {
     |          ^
  79 |   return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
  80 |     .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.init()))
  81 |     .pipe($.sass({
```

Here is my full [gulpfile.babel.js](https://pastebin.com/raw/9AuB9asg)

Can someone help me out :( already searched quite some time on it and can't find seem to fix it sadly

Comment: The first thing you have to do is rename your variable to maybe "gulpSass". Then, replace the "$.sass" with your variable i.e. "gulpSass"

This should fix your issue